# Could two different pairs of humans generate the same child

Tags: human-genetics

What I mean is this. Take male A, female A, male B, female B. Is it possible for the pair of male A x female A generate a child that is genetically identical to a child from the possible children from the pair male B x female B? Assuming neither of the four are related in any way. In simple terms, take me, for example: could my genetic code be generated from a different mother and a different father that my mother and father? Would the answer change if one of the parents is the same (say, male A x female A versus male A x female B)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'genetically identical'?

Comment: Well, say, two people with the same genetic code. Like twins, for example. Except not from the same parents.

Comment: 'Genetic code' isn't really a term that means anything. It sounds like I am being pedantic, but it terminology is very important for understanding. 'Genetic code' could mean either the same sequence of base pairs or the same sequence of codons. Which do you mean? And is there a specific reason why you are asking this question? Knowing this might help give a better answer, since sometimes the questions are based on a false understanding of the science.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] or delete your question accordingly. In particular, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). See also this sites criteria for ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework), which can apply to questions even if they are not assigned as homework. Thanks! 

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score 2):

[Forensic DNA analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_DNA#:%7E:text=Touch%20DNA%2C%20also%20known%20as,casually%20handled%2C%20or%20from%20footprints.) is essentially based on the fact that such coincidence cannot happen.

More precisely, the comparison between the DNA is done on multiple genetic locations, and the probabilities are evaluated that such a coincidence happen by chance. The standart use includes 13 locations, which is sufficient to confirm the identity *beyond reasonable doubt*:

```
Upon collection, the cells' DNA is extracted,
 and 13 genomic locations that vary among
 individuals are assessed to confirm suspects or exonerate those that are
 innocent.
```

This is to say that there is always a non-zero probability that the DNA of two different persons (even coming from the same pair of parents) are identical on all the 13 loci, but it is unreasonable to consider that such an event happens, given the human population size.